# Mercurial: File split into two files, how to track changes?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using Mercurial via TortoiseHG for a project. Just came across a situation like the following:

```
public static class Example
{
    public static void ExampleMethod()   { ... }
    public static void UnrelatedMethod() { ... }
}
```

Where I've had to split a file into two files, one new, one old:

```
public static class Example
{
    public static void ExampleMethod()   { ... }
}

// In a new file:
public static class Unrelated
{
    public static void UnrelatedMethod() { ... }
}
```

I know how to handle renames via Mercurial, but in this case is there any way to get the `Unrelated` class file to point to / clone the history of `Example` at the time it was forked off? Otherwise, if someone reviews the history, they won't know about previous changes to `UnrelatedMethod` unless they specifically know to look into `Example`'s history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you made proper copy (i.e. `hg copy`), then `hg log -f Unrelated` will follow history not just this file, but all it's ancestors too (`hg help log`)

Comment: Thanks for that. After seeing `hg copy` I amended my search terms and found the following link, which also talks about getting it to work in TortoiseHG. With only 1 upvote & ~200 visits, seems like it just didn't get good SEO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882356/copied-file-sharing-same-mutual-history-in-mercurial-tortoisehg.